# Make light pass through solid object

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

Using Blender Internal, is there a way to make light pass through a solid object, such as a cube, as if it wasn't there? The cube of course would still be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Go to the *Properties panel > Materials tab > Options menu* and deselect *Traceable*. Now, if, for example, you had a *Cube* with a *Point Lamp* inside, the point lamp would still affect the scene's lighting. You will, however, also have to have lamp(s) outside the cube to light it.

[image]

Also, consider looking at this .blend file. The cube in the center is the one with the lamp inside.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea how I missed this.

Comment: @Tritofic Glad to help. I learned about it in the BlenderGuru subway tutorial a while back.

Comment: How do I do this inside of Cycles however?

Comment: @NaturalistUbuntu Use LightPath > IsCameraRay as the fac in a Mix Shader node with your material in the bottom input socket and a Transparent BSDF in the top input socket.

Answer (score 2):

disable "traceable" in material options to prevent the object from casting a shadow and let light pass though it.